# Separate data with similar starting letters in different cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have following data in cell A1 -

```
EP10101010 | EP202020 | EP300005 | US789456 | US876543 | NZ90876 | LP98789 | LP88888
```

I want values that are starting with the same characters (e.g. EP) to be separated and grouped in one cell.

Desired output:

```
Cell A2 - EP10101010 | EP202020 | EP300005 
Cell A3 - US789456 | US876543
Cell A4 - NZ90876
Cell A5 - LP98789 | LP88888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim strng As Variant, strngs As Variant
    Dim lastStrngID As String, resStrng As String
    Dim rowIndex As Long

    strngs = Split(Replace(Range("A1"), " ", ""), "|")
    rowIndex = 2
    lastStrngID = Left(strngs(0), 2)
    For Each strng In strngs
        If Left(strng, 2) <> lastStrngID Then
            Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value = Left(resStrng, Len(resStrng) - 1)
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            lastStrngID = Left(strng, 2)
            resStrng = strng & " | "
        Else
            resStrng = resStrng & strng & "|"
        End If
    Next
    Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value = Left(resStrng, Len(resStrng) - 1)
End Sub
```

or, alternatively:

```
Sub main2()
    Dim strng As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each strng In Split(Replace(Range("A1"), " ", ""), "|")
            .Item(Left(strng, 2)) = .Item(Left(strng, 2)) & "|" & strng & "|"
        Next
        Range("A2").Resize(.count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items)
        With Range("A2").Resize(.count)
            .Replace "||", "--"
            .Replace "|", ""
            .Replace "--", " | "
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: can u tell me how to save the values in cell B2, B3, B4 instead of A2, A3, & A4.

Comment: yes sure. I'm not able to find accepted button. Please help me locating this.

Comment: ["To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: it's done. Thanks again. Further, Can u tell me how to save the values in cell B1, C1, D1 instead of A2, A3, & A4.

Comment: Further, Can u tell me how to save the values in cell B1, C1, D1 instead of A2, A3, & A4.

Comment: using the 2nd code , change all occurrences of `Range("A2").Resize(.count)` to `Range("B1").Resize(,.count)`

Comment: Thanks for response. But all values are not coming. I'm just getting following values - EP10101010 | EP202020 | EP300005 in B1 cell......... EP10101010 | EP202020 | EP300005 in C1 cell...... EP10101010 | EP202020 | EP300005 in D1 cell........... EP10101010 | EP202020 | EP300005 in E1 cell. I am not getting in Cell B1 - EP10101010 | EP202020 | EP300005 
Cell C1 - US789456 | US876543
Cell D1 - NZ90876
Cell E1 - LP98789 | LP88888

Comment: Yes! Sorry, you also have to change "Application.Transpose(.Items)" to ".Items"

Comment: Thanks again. You are a hero.

Comment: One last question, how to run this code for entire range of column A, right now its working only for cell A1. also how to remove extra pipelines in the beginning and end of the text. Thanks

Comment: Sir, One last question, how to run this code for entire range of column A, right now its working only for cell A1. also how to remove extra pipelines in the beginning and end of the text. Thanks –

Comment: As for the _"entire range"_  you have to wrap the code in some `For Each cell In Columns(1),SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ... Next cell` and then change `Range("A1")` to `cell` and `Range("A2")` to `cell.Offset(,1)`. As for the extra pipelines I'm not sure where they are: in my test with data as per your examples I ended up with no extra pipelines at all

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a newbie, Can u update the code for entire range, as I'm not able to understand where to add these extra lines?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a newbie, Can u update the code for entire range, as I'm not able to understand where to add these extra lines?

Comment: you'll stay a newbie all the time if you don't prove yourself in self-improving efforts! furthermore this is a _new_ issue with reference to your _original_ post. so you may make a _new_ post showing your code along with your efforts at reaching what you didn't succeed to (hoping you did it in the meanwhile!). the more effort shown on your part the more help you're likely to get

Answer (score 0):

I've got this code:

```
Public Function SplitStart(start As String, text As String) As String
Dim splitString() As String
Dim st As Variant
Dim returnstring As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim trimmed As String


splitString = Split(text, " | ")
returnstring = ""

For Each st In splitString
    trimmed = Trim(st)
    If Left(trimmed, Len(start)) = start Then
        If returnstring <> "" Then
            returnstring = returnstring + " | "
        End If
        returnstring = returnstring + trimmed
    End If
Next

SplitStart = returnstring
End Function
```

You insert it into a module and then you can use

```
=splitstart("EP";A1)
```

For example in A2